# C# cast object of type int to nullable enum

Tags: c#, enums, nullable

I just need to be able to cast an object to nullable enum. Object can be enum, null, or int. Thanks!

```
public enum MyEnum { A, B }
void Put(object value)
{
    System.Nullable<Myenum> val = (System.Nullable<MyEnum>)value;
}

Put(null);     // works
Put(Myenum.B); // works
Put(1);        // Invalid cast exception!!
```

Comment: You'll save yourself some trouble if you use strongly-typed declarations.  If you know that `Put` expects a `Nullable<MyEnum>`, why are you declaring it with an `object`?

Comment: @Ilya Kogan, that's a simplified version of the Put function, it deals with other data types, not just enum

Answer (score 55, accepted):

How about:

```
MyEnum? val = value == null ? (MyEnum?) null : (MyEnum) value;
```

The cast from boxed `int` to `MyEnum` (if `value` is non-null) and then use the implicit conversion from `MyEnum` to `Nullable<MyEnum>`.

That's okay, because you're allowed to unbox from the boxed form of an enum to its underlying type, or vice versa.

I believe this is actually a conversion which *isn't* guaranteed to work by the C# spec, but *is* guaranteed to work by the CLI spec. So as long as you're running your C# code on a CLI implementation (which you will be :) you'll be fine.

Comment: +1 I swear on a daily basis I take guidance from a Jon Skeet response on StackOverflow.  Well done sir.

Comment: Shorter way: `MyEnum? val = (MyEnum?) value ?? null`

Comment: How about: `MyEnum? val = value as MyEnum;`

Comment: @mikev2: That definitely behaves differently to my code, on the grounds that it will just return null if `value` isn't either an `int` or a `MyEnum`. It's hard to know whether the OP wanted that or not though. (You'd also need `value as MyEnum?;` rather than `value as MyEnum`.)

Comment: @mikev2: Additionally, `value as MyEnum?` returns null when `value` is a boxed int, unlike my version.

Comment: I _think_ I see -> it only really works as I'd intended when dealing with an object containing an int.  (with the `as MyEnum?` correction)

Comment: @mikev2: No, it doesn't work even then - `value as MyEnum?` returns null for a boxed int, whereas the OP wants it to return a non-null `MyEnum?` value in that case.

Comment: I've just tried this out every which way and it just fundamentally completely doesn't work, when you start with anything that isn't already the enum (and then pointless). Thanks for putting me straight!

Comment: @mikev2: You mean using "as"? Yes, indeed. Whereas the cast *does* work.

Comment: @JonSkeet I've tried something like that earlier, and when I deployed code, build failed, and still I don't understand why, here is my code: `MyNullableEnum = product.type.HasValue ? (MyNullableEnum)product.type : null`. Thanks mate!

Comment: @Roxy'Pro: Please *carefully* compare your code with the code in my answer.

Comment: @JonSkeet I know your code works, and when I edited my code to be like yours everything works, and I'm trying to understand why my code didn't work. I just said 'otherwise' be null  `: null ` and that was the issue. But I'm not sure why since my enum is nullable it should accepts null as a value ? Thanks Jon

Comment: @Roxy'Pro: The nullable enum type does allow a null value... but the expression `product.type.HasValue ? (MyNullableEnum)product.type : null` is invalid by the language rules of C#. The variable or property you're trying to assign the result to is not involved in inferring the type of the conditional expression. If you want a lot more detail, ask a new question - the detailed answer would be long and refer to specific bits of the C# spec.

Answer (score 13):

This is because you're unboxing and casting in a single operation, which is not allowed.  You can only unbox a type to the same type that is boxed inside of the object.

For details, I recommend reading Eric Lippert's blog: [Representation and Identity](https://ericlippert.com/2009/03/03/representation-and-identity/).

Comment: Actually, not quite. See my answer - you *can* unbox from a boxed `int` to an enum type (with `int` as the underlying type), or from a boxed enum value to its underlying type.

Comment: @Jon: True - but that's also somewhat an edge case (only works because the "enum" is actually an "int" in this specific case) - what happens when the OP passes 0.0 into the method?  Or they try to use this technique with an enum backed by something other than Int32?  Those will still cause a problem...

Comment: Then it will break. But the OP does say: "Object can be enum, null, or int." In other words, the solution I've given works for the problem as presented. We don't know what behaviour is desired in other situations.

Answer (score 4):

*a bit offtopic*

For Those, who needs the result to be null when the value is not defined in the enum;

One should use either :

```
typeof(MyEnum).IsEnumDefined(val)
```

or

```
Enum.IsDefined(typeof(MyEnum), val)
```

Here is the usage example:

```
enum MyEnum { one = 1, three = 3, four=4 }

static MyEnum? CastIntAsNullableEnum(int value) 
{
    if (!Enum.IsDefined(typeof(MyEnum), value)) return null;
    return (MyEnum?)value;            
}

static void CastIntAsNullableEnumTest()
{
    for(int i =0; i<=5; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("converted {0} is {1}", i, CastIntAsNullableEnum(i));
    }                        
}
```

*Thanks to John Thiriet (johnthiriet.com) for the solution*

Answer (score 1):

When you are assigning a value to a nullable type you have to be aware that it is not the same as the underlying type(at least in this case). So in order to perform the cast you need to unbox first:

```
void Put(object value)
{
    if (value != null)
    {
        System.Nullable<Myenum> val = (System.Nullable<MyEnum>)(MyEnum)value;
    }
}
```

Comment: This won't work either. This code has the same mistake: unboxing and casting in the same operation. `Put` should get `MyEnum?` as the parameter.

Comment: +1 because it *does* work. Those saying it doesn't should *try* it :)

Comment: I did try it before I posted it though :)

Comment: May be @IlyaKogan meant it doesnt work because `val` is not assigned in case `value` is `null`.