# Cast Int to Generic Nullable Enum in C#

Tags: c#, generics, casting, enums, nullable

I would like to cast an int value as nullable enum used a generic function.  I thought it would be easy, especially with all the with all the SO about the enum / int casting.  The closest question I've found is [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10387095/cast-int-to-generic-enum-in-c-sharp), but unfortunately, it doesn't handle the nullable enums.  [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5199419/c-sharp-cast-object-of-type-int-to-nullable-enum) solve the Nullable enums casting question but not with the generic.

Here's a simplified example of what I'm trying to do:

```
public enum SouthParkCharacters
{
    Stan = 0,
    Kyle = 1,
    Eric = 2,
    Kenny = 3
}

public static T CastNullableEnum<T>(int value)
{
    return (T)(object)((int?)value).Value;
}


public static T SomeFunction<T>(this int anyEnumValue)
{
        SouthParkCharacters? spc = SouthParkCharacters.Kenny;

        spc = CastNullableEnum<SouthParkCharacters>(3); //I am working!
        spc = CastNullableEnum<SouthParkCharacters?>(3); //Raise error Specified cast is not valid.

        //This function will be public so I won't have control over the T
        T finalValue = CastNullableEnum<T>(anyEnumValue); //Raise error Specified cast is not valid.

        return finalValue;

}
```

As you can see in last function, a cast for a non-nullable enum is working.  The problem is that I want to be able to call the CastNullableEnum from an other generic function, which could use a nullable enum as a generic type.

I know you can pass a generic type as a nullable generic `CastNullableEnum<T?>` but can we do the opposite (i.e. pass the nullable underlying type to generic function)?

If this can't be done, then I guess the solution would be to find the right way to cast an enum value in the CastNullableEnum function.

Comment: I think C# support for generic enums is a bit weak.  I really wish you could say "where T : enum", but "where T : struct" is the closest you can get.  That said, why do you want to be able to have the same method return both a bare enum and a Nullable?  It seems better to have your function allways return Nullable<T> and force your caller to check if the result is valid. And I'm assuming you want to return null if the enum doesn't actually have a member with the integer value.  Or maybe I'm missing something?

Comment: SouthParkCharacters? is not a truct, so where T:struct is not applicable here.

Comment: To make a long story short, this function will be used to map data from a dbDataReader to a property of a given object.  As I don't have control about the given object nor the Generic type, I would like to handle every casting issue on my side.

Comment: @The_Black_Smurf Have you considered defining one of your enum values as None, i.e. `None = 0,` rather than trying to use null? Also worth considering is storing your enum values in the database as a string (nvarchar). It increases readability when querying or reporting and is easily handled with the ToString and Enum.TryParse methods.

Comment: @JamieSee, yes, I did consider using a none value in my enum for my needs.  The problem is that my library might be used as a third party so I won't be able to control the Generic type provided to my function (nor the enum structure / the way it will be stored in the DB).

Comment: @The_Black_Smurf I don't know if it fits your case at all, but you might find http://specializedenum.codeplex.com interesting.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I probably read the question wrong, buy you could grab the underlying type from the nullable  and use `Enum.Parse` instead of a direct cast.

```
public T CastNullableEnum<T>(int value) 
{
    var enumType = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(typeof(T));
    if (Enum.IsDefined(enumType, value)) 
    {
        return (T)(object)Enum.Parse(enumType, value.ToString());
    }
    return default(T);
}

var test1 = CastNullableEnum<SouthParkCharacters?>(3); 
//returns Kenny

var test2 = CastNullableEnum<SouthParkCharacters?>(9); 
// returns null
```

Answer (score 3):

This will work:

```
public static T IntToEnum<T>(object value)
{
    if (value == null)
        return (T)value;

    else if (typeof(T).IsEnum)
        return (T)value;

    else if (Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(typeof(T))?.IsEnum == true)
        return (T)Enum.ToObject(Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(typeof(T)), (int)value);

    throw new Exception(string.Format("Value cannot be converted from {0} to {1}", value.GetType().Name, typeof(T).Name));
}
```

can be used for nullable and regular enums

```
public enum Codes
{
    A = 1,
    B = 2,
    C = 3
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine(IntToEnum<Codes?>(1));
    Console.WriteLine(IntToEnum<Codes?>(null));
    Console.WriteLine(IntToEnum<Codes>(2));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Interesting question. The problem with this code is to cast integer to nullable enum, which is not possible.

```
  SouthParkCharacters? enumValue = (SouthParkCharacters?)int.MaxValue;
  if (enumValue.HasValue)
     {
         Console.WriteLine("it still has value");
     }
```

The above code is running and it results the enumValue still HasValue.

But anyway, if you take a look at the C# code after the compiling, it will be something like this:

```
public static T CastNullableEnum<T>(int value)
    {
        Type type = typeof(T);
        return (T)((object)value);
    }
    public static T SomeFunction<T>(int anyEnumValue)
    {
        Program.SouthParkCharacters? spc = new Program.SouthParkCharacters?(Program.SouthParkCharacters.Kenny);
        spc = new Program.SouthParkCharacters?(Program.CastNullableEnum<Program.SouthParkCharacters>(new int?(3)));
        spc = Program.CastNullableEnum<Program.SouthParkCharacters?>(new int?(3));
        return Program.CastNullableEnum<T>(new int?(anyEnumValue));
    }
```

Now, notice the

```
spc = new Program.SouthParkCharacters?(Program.CastNullableEnum<Program.SouthParkCharacters>(new int?(3)));
```

That's where the Unspecified Cast Exception comes from; because the new SouthParkCharacters?(int value) expect an Integer.

Funny thing is that you won't encounter this problem when you run with Immediate. Interesting, huh?

Comment: Yes, I noticed the difference with immediate window... it took me 15 minutes to understand what was going on with my tests.  It's really a weird behavior.