# Casting to nullable enum

Tags: c#, enums

I have a question about casting to nullable enum. Here is a code:

```
enum Digits
{
    One = 1,
    Two = 2
}

void Main()
{
    int one = 1;
    object obj = one;
    var en = (Digits?) obj;
    Console.WriteLine(en);
}
```

It gives me `InvalidCastException` in line #11.
But if I omit '?' symbol in that line, it gives correct result "One" but I don't want to lose 'nullability'.
As a workaround I now use `var en = (Digits?) (int?) obj;` and it works although I'm not sure of full correctness of such a solution.

But I wonder **why does casting to nullable enum fail in the first case?**

I expected that casting to nullable types acts as follows:
- cast to non-nullable type, if success then cast to nullable type
- if `null` is passed then result would be `null` as well
But it seems to be not true.

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5199419/c-sharp-cast-object-of-type-int-to-nullable-enum

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're working with *boxed* `int` value. Unbox it back into `int` first:

```
  var en = (Digits?) (int) obj; // note "(int)"
```

If `obj` can be assigned to `null` you can use *ternary operator*:

```
  Digits? en = null == obj ? null : (Digits?) (int) obj;
```